# Python .sum() is giving me a different result to plt.bar() and sns.barplot(), which is correct?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset which looks something like:

```
User ID | Group | Revenue
101     |   1   |    0
102     |   2   |    1.3
103     |   2   |    0.5
103     |   1   |    2.3
104     |   1   |    1.4
...     |   ... |   ...
```

I want to know the revenue per group. I've done this:

```
df.groupby('Group').Revenue.sum()
```

which has returned:

```
Group
Group 1    643.00
Group 2    351.47
Name: Revenue, dtype: float64
```

I've then plotted this in a matplotlib by doing the following:

```
plt.bar(df.Group, df.Revenue)
plt.show()
```

and I get this chart back:

[image]
Group 1 is on the left.

Trying it out with seaborn, I wrote this code:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Group', y='Revenue')
plt.show()
```

and I got this graph back:

[image]
Group 1 is on the right

I'm looking to get the sum of the revenue per group, but not sure which result is correct, and what the others are trying to show. Not sure how to change the graphs, if they are wrong, to show the true revenue total.

Thanks.

Comment: Seaborn barplot shows you the average for each group and either the standard deviation or a confidence interval (depending on the given parameters) of that average.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've done a group by, you can plot the bar chart using that group by object:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 343], [1, 300], [2, 300], [2, 51.47]], columns=['Group', 'Revenue'])

In [9]: df.groupby('Group').Revenue.sum().plot.bar()
Out[9]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f97345e7710>

In [10]: plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this however I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'plt'`.  What I'm trying right now is putting the `groupby` code into `plt.bar()`. Do you know why I'm getting a different answer for the graphs compared to the sum?

Comment: The Series object does not have a plt attribute, but it has a plot attribute. Have you copy pasted my answer ?

Comment: Thanks, this has given me a graph showing the same as my sum. I originally thought 'plot' was a reference to pyplot, which I imported as plt. Anyway, thanks for showing me that!